# Enable HTML5 mode in JHipster (Angular2)

Tags: angular, jhipster

Which would be the correct way to enable html5 mode for pretty url's in JHipster when using Angular2?

Checking the [JHipster documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/tips/010_tip_configuring_html_5_mode.html) I can only find the how-to for AngularJS.

Comment: It should be the default unless JHipsterexplicitly makes this not so. I don't know about any JHipster specific way, but (manually) look for a `RouterModule.forRoot` somewhere, If it's configured like `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})`, remove the `{useHash: true}`. This would cause Angular to use the hashing strategy instead of the html5 path strategy

Comment: This won't work out of the box in JHipster, there have been several duplicate questions about this here.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou were you able to find some link? I found only AngularJS (v1) related topics

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536918/unable-to-login-after-html5mode-activation-in-jhipster-app but it won't help. Also the dev team did try to do it for 4.0 but postponed it as it was not trivial and not urgent.